# Objects I add with jQuery are not displaying?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery, and I am trying to add new elements to an existing div

My jQuery:

```
function GetXML1Response(results) {
        $(results).filter("Child").each(function () {
            var newDiv = $("<div>").text("Value: " + $(this).attr("value"));
            $("#contentDiv").append(newDiv);
        });
    }
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="contentDiv">
        <div>TEST 1</div>
    </div>
```

If I look at it in the debugger, it adds the new divs as expected, but they do not appear, and on the next call, they have disappeared.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I think I may know where the problem is coming from.  This function is triggered as the callback to a WebMethod.  I suspect that it may be happening on a different thread, and thus the changes made are being lost?

Comment: Can you show me what the html of your page is that your debugger reports?

Comment: Give us the code in http://jsbin.com/

Comment: Try this: http://jsbin.com/ahanu5/edit  
Sorry if I entered it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `Child` nodes are nested, you should use the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method  or the [`children()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method  instead of the [`filter()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method .

```
$(results).find("Child").each(...  // searches all descendants
```

or

```
$(results).children("Child").each(... // searches only immediate descendants
```

Comment: The .filter call does return the nodes, the .find and the .children methods do not.  When I use the .filter method, it is iterating over the child list correctly, and adding the new DIVs correctly, but as soon as the function exits, they disappear.  It is like something is going out of scope.

Comment: @Sako73: Your jsbin showed them as descendants. Anyway, what is triggering the code? Are you clicking a link?

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) incorrectly, you want [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
function GetXML1Response(results) {
    $(results).find("Child").each(function () {
        var newDiv = $("<div>").text("Value: " + $(this).attr("value"));
        $("#contentDiv").append(newDiv);
    });
}
```

You're handing `.filter` a single `<rootElement>` and asking it filter out everything that isn't `<Child>`, the result is an empty list. If you do the same with `.find` then you will be giving `.find` `<rootElement>` and you're asking it to extract all the `<Child>` elements that it contains (and this is what you want to happen).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.  Not jQuery at all.  I had an HTML Button, and it was automatically doing a postback.  When I added

```
return false;
```

after the function call, it worked as expected.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it must have been a link. It is very helpful if you post a full picture of the code instead of just the narrowest part that seems to be broken. :o)